# How can I recognize a "parked free" website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib2

I have a long list with urls and some of them are "parked-free" by godaddy
Is there any technical way to recognize such pages without opening them on browser?
The page is technically live and

`requests.head('url').status_code`

returns 200 so it doesn't help

Trying to get the content, I only receive "Enable Javascript..." message

I also tried to use some metatags but they are not visible in beautiful soup

Selenium could probably help, but I would like to avoid it for this specific problem

Is there any simplier solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

If it's just godaddy, you can try either resolving the domain or trying to make a request with random path (say, `/dkfiwifhe`). The few domain I tested all resolve to 34.102.136.180, and return HTTP 200 for any path.

Of course, this can change anytime and likely won't work on other parking sites, sedo resolve to 91.195.241.137, including all the subdomain (godaddy return nxdomain for random subdomain and canonical naked domain for www), but return 403 for any path.

Depending on how many unique parking sites in your list, you might as well just look up at list of parking sites provider and craft special script for all of them.

Another alternative is, some DNS providers allows filtering parked domain, so you can just attempt to resolve against them. Service recommendation is off topic though, so you can just google them yourself.